# Check for overlapping dates range from strings swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, sorting

I have this collection of Event objects that I'm getting from a JSON, I'm gonna show them order by startDate in a tableView. I want to show a warning when two events are overlapping, how can I check when two events overlap? Should I create date objects? Or how can I check the range with the given strings? I want to thank everyone in advance for taking the time to read my problem!

```
struct Event {
    let title: String
    let startDate: String
    let endDate: String
}
```

Comment: *"Should I create date objects?"* - Yes, as a personal preference, if the data been supplied represents a date/time value, I like to have those converted to the support type.  You will also find it MUCH simpler to deal with in the long run

Comment: The dates are presented as this "November 29, 2021 10:00 PM" as Strings, I'm assuming to create date from string, but any idea on how to see if events overlap?

Comment: You can create two date intervals and check if they intersect

Comment: Is this still applicable for an array containing several events? Should I check compare each date to every other date?

Comment: Check the duplicate post